# Diferença de Angular JS para NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Qual Diferença de Angular JS para NodeJS?

Qual é mais utilizado?

Existe algum tutorial que vocês recomendam pra quem esta iniciando que ensine um CRUD em cada um deles?

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre um Elefante e um gafanhoto? São duas coisas bem distintas.

Comment: A pergunta não me parece ter sentido algum, ambas tecnologias nada tem haver, a pergunta não ajudará ninguem, parece falta de uma pesquisa previa, é quase o mesmo que eu perguntar qual a diferença de HTML e PHP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Node.js

É um interpretador de código JavaScript que funciona do lado do servidor. Seu objetivo é ajudar programadores na criação de aplicações de alta escalabilidade (como um servidor web), com códigos capazes de manipular dezenas de milhares de conexões simultâneas, numa única máquina física. O Node.js é baseado no interpretador V8 JavaScript Engine (interpretador de JavaScript open source implementado pelo Google em C++ e utilizado pelo Chrome). Foi criado por Ryan Dahl em 2009, e seu desenvolvimento é mantido pela empresa Joyent, onde Dahl trabalha.

> AngularJS

AngularJS é um framework JavaScript open-source que roda no lado do client(navegador), mantido pelo Google, que auxilia na execução de single-page applications. Seu objetivo é aumentar aplicativos que podem ser acessados por um navegador web, foi construído sob o padrão model-view-view-model (MVVM), em um esforço para facilitar tanto o desenvolvimento quanto o teste dos aplicativos.

A biblioteca lê o HTML que contém tags especiais e então executa a diretiva na qual esta tag pertence, e faz a ligação entre a apresentação e seu modelo, representado por variáveis JavaScript comuns. O valor dessas variáveis JavaScript podem ser setadas manualmente, ou via um recurso JSON estático ou dinâmico.

**Resumindo o AngularJS é um framework para desenvolvimento no frontend e o NodeJS é para desenvolvimento backend, e os dois usam o JavaScript como linguagem de programação.**

Fontes: [AngularJS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) & [NodeJS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)